# Как работает конструкция данных медиа-запросов?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

На одном из уроков от хорошего веб мастера в ютубе, нашел такую конструкцию для описания медиа-запросов. Он говорит что постоянно использует ее в работе.

```
@import "vars"

/*==========  Desktop First  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px)
/**/
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px)
/**/
/* Small Devices, Tablets */
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)
/**/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px)
/**/


/*==========  Mobile First  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px)
/**/


/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px)
/**/


/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px)
/**/


/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px)
/**/


/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px)
/**/
```

Каким образом не конфликтую запросы max-width : 320px + max-width : 480px , то есть тут правила для разрешений до 320px и с 320px до 480px 
c этими

min-width : 320px + min-width : 480px   ?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что не конфликтуют?)

Comment: как в медиа запросах может быть конфликт? если попадает под условие то выполняется, если нет то нет, одновременно может хоть миллион условий выполнятся учитывая приоритеты

Comment: конфликтуют , описался

Comment: я имею ввиду. зачем тогда создавать такую структуру. по сути первая часть переписывается второй

Comment: @Anton, например затем, что тут описаны два подхода: _Desktop First_ и _Mobile First_ и обычно применяют один из них, а не оба сразу :)